# Fetch every record from Oracle Database and Insert it into SQL Server database table without missing of any data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I've setup a SQL Server job to fetch data from Oracle database to SQL Server database table but whenever bulk data need to be fetched, the job fails to insert every possible records into SQL Server table.

The problem is found to be in SQL Server while trying to fetch data from Oracle Server using linked server and SQL jobs.

```
insert into customers
(
  address,
  name
)
select address, name from openquery([192.168.255.255],'select address, name from customer_info
where last_login_date > '''+@date+'''')
```

The problem arises when there are bulk of records to be fetched from Oracle server database to SQL Server database table. For example, If 500 records are to be fetched from Oracle Server, then only half or less records are being inserted in SQL Server database and half of them are missed out.

Please note that I run SQL job every 10 seconds. We must run the job every 10 seconds, so request to provide some means or ways to extract every possible data by any means possible.

Comment: What makes you think it's the SQL Server side? There are a lot of variables here, like the `login_date` filter. There really isn't enough info to help here. You should work out _exactly_ which records are missing, you should experiment with filters to see if it makes a difference, and you should check the SQL Server log and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Well. I'm trying to fetch a data using alike condition where batch data will be inserted into oracle and these data has to be fetched on basis of a date filter into our SQL table. Few days ago, around 600 data were being inserted into oracle within 9 seconds interval but only 250 data were fetched successfully whereas remaining data weren't being fetched. So is there any possible ways to fetch all the data into SQL tables from Oracle database without missing the data. Note that the job must be run on 10 seconds interval in production environment.

Comment: It’s normal operation for it to fetch all the data and there’s no clue what the issue is. Based on your description I’m not convinced there just isn’t a misunderstanding with the Oracle query.

Comment: Have you checked clock on each server (SQL server and whatever server that populates `last_login_date`)? What about transaction locking e.g. data is still being written as you are trying to read it? IMO there are lots of trivial things you need to check first before blaming database engines for dropping half your data.

Comment: What is @date variable? How do you calculate it for each Job run?